# Are in vs are included in vs are featured in

Tags: word-choice

Would you explain the difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> 1. Is it okay that several scenes with Dana are **in the movie**?
> 2. Is it okay that several scenes with Dana are **included in the movie**?
> 3. Is it okay that several scenes with Dana are **featured in the movie**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning. They all mean the same thing.

In the first sentence the verb (whether *included* or *featured*) is understood.

You might look for nuances of difference between **featured** and **included** but you would have to look very hard.

It's a bit like asking the difference between **shutting the door** and **closing the door**. The answer is that they mean the same thing.

Comment: "Featured" has an implication of prominence as well as presence. "Included" often has a sense that they might have been left out.